# How can i return from a function a value that just can't be changed?

Tags: c++

I know a function can return a const reference, but are there other methods to achieve this kind of behavior? Meaning, i want to return a value that just can't be modified.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;  

class A {  
public:  
    A( int x, int y): _x(x), _y(y) {};  
    int _x;  
    int _y;  
};  

const A genObjA()
{
    return A( 0,0 );
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    A new_obj = genObjA();
    std::cout << new_obj._x;
    new_obj._x = 10; // user can change new_obj
    std::cout << new_obj._x;

}
```

This will print

```
0
10
```

Comment: Unless you return a non-const reference, a value you return can't be modified (though it's copy may). What's the goal of the exercise? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I fail to understand what OP is asking..

Comment: Sorry, first time posting a question and failed to formulate it correctly. This is what i want to achieve: i want to return an object that you can't change even though you make a copy of it. For example, i have a class Date{...} and a function that returns an object of type Date. I want to prevent the user from changing the returned object.

Comment: @user3529308 then return a constant object, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that if i do something like this: Object new_obj = function_name(); , then i get a copy of the Object and i can change new_obj.

Comment: `int my_function(){ return 7; }` -- does this qualify?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return a const reference, you can return a const object.

```
const Object function_name() {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if i do something like this: Object new_obj = function_name(); , then i get a copy of the Object and i can change new_obj.

Comment: no you can't change that object unless you const-cast away the constness with some tricks

Comment: @user3529308, What you're trying to do is extremely illogical in the context of C++. If the caller makes a copy, it's completely up to them whether to modify the copy. You can disable copying if that part is a problem.

Comment: Yes, that`s an idea. I do agree it`s quite illogical, but i find it an interesting puzzle to think about.

Answer (score 0):

You don't modify returned value, you modify it's copy. In this code, you can't do `genObjA()._x=10;`.

To reach your goal, you can write extra class:

```
class A_const{
protected:
    int _x;  
    int _y;
    operator=(const A_base&)=default;
public: 
    A()=default;
    A(const A_base&)=default;
    A( int x, int y): _x(x), _y(y) {};
    int x(){return _x;}
    int y(){return _y;}
    //or
    int get_x(){return _x;}
    int get_y(){return _y;}
};

class A {  
public:
    using A_const::A_const;
    A(const A&)=default;
    int& x(){return _x;}
    int& y(){return _y;}
    //or
    int& set_x(int val){return _x=val;}
    int& set_y(int val){return _y=val;}
};

const A_const genObjA_const(){
    return A_const(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: at least make `_x`, `_y` and the assign operator protected :D

Comment: I completely forgot about this xD Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fool-proof modification safeguard, you can use the [PIMPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_class_data_pattern) idiom.

However, if you have reasonable faith in the sanity of your coleagues who work with your class, just use a const-reference. If you want to be sure, document the reason *why* you don't want the object to be modified, so that your fellows can follow your thoughts (and come to the same conclusion). The PIMPL idiom tries to save you from the determined fools. But determined fools will even work around PIMPL, so there's little point in messing up your code in the attempt.